# vuejs class binding on dynamically loaded elements

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, jinja2

I try to use vuejs on some elements. This is how I load the script in my jinja2 template:

```
{% block tail %}
  {{ super() }}
   <script src="/static/assets/js/vue.global.js"></script>
<script>
  const { createApp } = Vue

  createApp({
    data() {
      return {
        message: 'form-control shadow'
      }
    },
    delimiters: ['[[',']]']
  }).mount('#questions')
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

By clicking a button an html fragment as following is appended to a page element using jQuery.

```
<ul :class="message" class="" id="yesno">...</ul>
```

But the `message` isn't bound to the element. However if I use this solution:

```
<ul  class="[[ message ]]"  id="yesno">...</ul>
```

The variable is set and it works. What could be the problem? Also, is my second solution an alternative for the first one?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const { createApp } = Vue;

const App = { 
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'form-control shadow'
    }
  },
  delimiters: ['[[',']]'],
  methods: {
    addToDiv() {
      const el = document.getElementById("dynamic");
      el.innerHTML='<ul :class="message" class="" >&lt;ul :class="message"</ul>'
    }  
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
const vm = app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
.form-control.shadow {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <ul :class="message" class="" >&lt;ul :class="message"</ul>
  <ul  class="[[ message ]]" >&lt;ul class="[[ message ]]"</ul>
  <ul  :class="[[ message ]]" >&lt;ul :class="[[ message ]]"</ul>
  <div id='dynamic'></div>
  <button @click="addToDiv()">Add &lt;ul :class="message"</button>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Since you redefine the "Mustaches" for the [template text interpolation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html)
to `delimiters: ['[[',']]']`, you have to use them in the template.

While default delimiters for text interpolation does not work with [attribute bindings](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#attribute-bindings).

> Mustaches cannot be used inside HTML attributes. Instead, use a `v-bind`
> directive

The custom delimiters do work with attribute bindings, together with `v-bind`

So, you possibly have this `:class="[[ message ]]"` in your code and it does work. See the playground below.

The problem with adding new elements using jQuery or Vanilla JS, is that the Vue binding occurs by mounting the template and will not be triggered when you manipulate the DOM outside Vue. Check the <kbd>Add</kbd> in the playground. The added HTML is not processed by Vue and there is still `v-bind` shortcut by `:class`.

[image: Add button result]

So, if you want to add new elements, do it using Vue.